# Android. Вызов функции из BroadcastReciver в службу

Tags: java, android, функции, service, broadcast-receiver

голова кругом уже... суть вот в чем.

имеется простенькое приложенице, состоящее из одной активити, одного сервиса и бродкастресивера. активити запускает службу, которая в свою очередь рулит уведомлениями. бродкаст используется в качестве "будильника", то есть будит устройство по расписанию. мне вот необходимо сделать так, чтоб по очередному событию в бродкасте обновилось уведомление (проще говоря, ума не хватает как достучаться до функций в сервисе)...
пробовал даже биндить, но быстро понял что это плохая затея.. через глобальные переменные даже возникала мысль сделать... как это по уму провернуть?

Comment: Данные в сервис можно отправить через IBinder который вернется после OnServiceConnected. Какого рода информацию вы хотите передать? Логика создания нотификаций в сервисе находится? Тогда можноиз сервиса  создать PendingIntent / Intent на вашу активити и показать через NotificationManager, активити откроется когда пользователь кликнет на нотификацию.

Comment: да пока что мне просто надо передать в сервис о том, что сработал ресивер по таймеру.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выкрутился из ситуации вот так

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent in = new Intent("AppService");
    in.putExtra("Data","Проверка связи.");
    context.sendBroadcast(in);       
}
```

и прием в сервисе:

```
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    //Регистрация приемника
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("AppService");
    BroadcastReceiver service = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("AppService")) {

                String message = intent.getStringExtra("Data");
                Toast.makeText(context,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(service, filter);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

вроде работает. не знаю насколько это грамотно

Answer (score 2):

Передавайте `intent` (в который сложили необходимые данные) из `BroadcastReceiver` в `service` и разбирайте/обрабатывайте в `onStartCommand()`. Показывайте/обновляйте нотификацию.

Comment: в ресивере я прописал
         intentToSevr = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("EXTRA", "1");
        intentToSevr.putExtras(bundle);
  
  в сервисе
  
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {       
           String message = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA");
            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
 
 но оно отрабатывает только при первом запуске сервиса

Comment: Пропишите `return START_STICKY` в `onStartCommand()`